# Smart Home Test Google Action giving 500 Error

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am trying to create Smart Home Test Google Action but when try to test it in Google Assistant app it redirects to 500 Error page.

I am following this Smart Washer example :

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/#2

but not able to proceed to next step because of this 500 Error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like an error in your OAuth integration. Did you make sure to use the cloud functions that you deployed as part of the codelab?

Comment: Using only Google login which is most simplest of all oauth options. How can there be oauth integration issue?

Comment: This is the link that's getting 500 error https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=iswitch-9213f_dev&return_url=assistant-handoff://complete&user_email=iswitchremote@gmail.com&redirect_uri=assistant-handoff%3A%2F%2Fcomplete

Comment: Smart home integrations do not work with Google Sign-In. The codelab source includes two functions for OAuth.

Comment: Can I use third-party Oauth 2.0 solution like Facebook or GitHub?